# Python regex - Match words only containing A, B, or C

Tags: python, regex, match

What regex expression can I use to match words that are made of up ONLY the characters A, B, or C? For example the regex would catch ABCBACBACBABBABCC and A and B and C but would not catch ABCD, ABC1, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What about `\b[ABC]+\b`?  Does that work?

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'\b[ABC]+\b')
>>> regex.match('AACCD')  #No match
>>> regex.match('AACC')   #match
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x11bb578>
>>> regex.match('A')      #match
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x11bb5e0>
```

`\b` is a word boundary.  So here we match anything that is a word boundary followed by only `A`,`B` or `C` characters until the next word boundary.

---

For those who don't like regex, we can use `set` objects here as well:

```
>>> set("ABC").issuperset("ABCABCABC")
True
>>> set("ABC").issuperset("ABCABCABC1")
False
```

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression you are looking for is `r'\b([ABC]+)\b'`.

You can compile it:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'\b([ABC]+)\b')
```

and then you can do some things with it:

```
>>> regex.match('ABC') # find a match with whole string.
>>> regex.search('find only the ABC') # find a match within the whole string.
>>> regex.findall('this will find only the ABC elements in this ABC test text') # find 2 matches.
```

If you want to ignore the case, then use:

```
>>> regex = re.compile(r'\b([ABC]+)\b', re.I)
```